# Cannot install Ubuntu 18 in VMWare Player

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, vmware, iso-image

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18 with an iso from Canonical in VMWare Workstation Player version 16.
For the CD I am setting Connected, COnnected at Power On, Use ISO file with the path to the ISO file.

However it seems that VMWARE Player does not detect the iso file and tries to boot from the network which results in an error: Operating system not found.
I have already changed the boot order in the VM Bios such that the CD-ROM is tried first. I have tried to configure the CDROM as sata, scsi or ide all with the same result.

Can anyone please help?

I have installed before Ubuntu in VMWare Player (Ubuntu 16.04 on WMWare Workstation Player 15) but it has always worked.
Should I configure something, especially for version 16 of the player?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik For hypervisors we typically don't burn media but use the ISO files directly. What may be happening here is a corrupt ISO but in any case one must ask: WHY 18.04? Support ends in April 2023. Please download an use a SUPPORTED release.

Comment: Yes. This was the solution. I downloaded Ubuntu 20 and 22 isos. VMWare Player recognized both and started the installation.

Comment: For completeness and to avoid misunderstandings: The Ubuntu 18.04 SHOULD have worked the exact same way but, as commented before, the file was likely corrupt. The newer downloaded ones are likely fine but, for the record, you should always verify ISO after downloading (google it, too much for a simple comment).